# change the value of an array in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have array in this way

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [qa_verified] => 0          
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [qa_verified] => 1               
            )
        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [qa_verified] => 2               
            )
)
```

i need to change into

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qa_verified] => invalidate          
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qa_verified] => approve               
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [qa_verified] => reject               
        )
)
```

i have to change the value of qa_verified key depending on the status
`0 = invalidate`, `1= approve`, `2=reject`

i tried on array_walk, but unable to get result

any one help me on this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$lookup = array('invalidate', 'approve', 'reject');
array_walk(
    $myArray,
    function(&$entry) use ($lookup) {
        $entry->qa_verified = $lookup[$entry->qa_verified];
    }
);

var_dump($myArray);
```

Comment: I was going to post an answer with foreach, but this is much better :)